# Why doesn't System.Text.Json.JsonElement have TryGetString() or TryGetBoolean()

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I'm parsing some JSON data with the .NET Core `System.Text.Json` namespace which returns `JsonElement` objects.

For Int32 types, for example, `JsonElement` has a `GetInt32()` which will return the value as an integer or throw an exception if it isn't an integer, and there is also a `TryGetInt32()` which copies the parsed value to an `out` variable and returns true or false depending on whether it was able to parse correctly.

The same applies to almost all other primitive types but for some reason, `GetBoolean()` and `GetString()` have no `try...` equivalent even though they also will throw an exception if the value cannot be parsed correctly.

This seems such an obvious oversight, it makes me think I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone explain why they aren't needed?

Comment: That is because each data in json data could be converted to string successfully so that no need to have `TryGetString()`.For `boolean` data,it could always be true unless you pass the number zero.So I think it no need to be given the `TryGetBoolean` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPD**

Don't mind the original answer, the `TryGet_number_type` methods don't work as I (and I assume you) would expect - they will throw if you will try to get "number_type" from element which `ValueKind` is not a `Number` ([`decimal` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.trygetdecimal?view=netcore-3.1#exceptions) for example).

So this `TryGet...` API basically tries to parse inner value as some concrete type but only if value is of valid [json type](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) for this attempted concrete type(`Number` for all numeric types, `String` for `Guid`, `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`), otherwise it will throw `InvalidOperationException`,  therefore it would not make sense to have an `TryGetString` and `TryGetBoolean` methods  because there is no ambiguity here (string is always a string and boolean is always a boolean) and they would behave exactly the same as `Get` counterpart.

**Original answer**:

Was not able to find any reasoning for not having this API's, but implementing them yourself should not be a big issue (still would be nice to have them in standard library):

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getboolean?view=netcore-3.1) `GetBoolean` throws if value's `ValueKind` is neither `True` nor `False`.

```
public static bool TryGetBoolean(this JsonElement je, out bool parsed)
{
    var (p, r) = je.ValueKind switch
    {
        JsonValueKind.True => (true, true),
        JsonValueKind.False => (false, true),
        _ => (default, false)
    };    
    parsed = p;
    return r;
}
```

And `GetString` [throws](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getstring?view=netcore-3.1) if value's `ValueKind` is neither `String` nor `Null`:

```
public static bool TryGetsString(this JsonElement je, out string parsed)
{
    var (p, r) = je.ValueKind switch
    {
        JsonValueKind.String => (je.GetString(), true),
        JsonValueKind.Null => (null, true),
        _ => (default, false)
    };  
    parsed = p;
    return r;
}
```

And sample test:

```
using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(@"{""bool"": true, ""str"": ""string""}"))
{
    if (document.RootElement.GetProperty("bool").TryGetBoolean(out var b))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }

    if (document.RootElement.GetProperty("str").TryGetString( out var s))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I see it now - looks like the "TryGet" doesn't try quite as hard as C#'s built-in "TryParse" methods which is what I was assuming they would do

Comment: @Andy the same for me, though you can make the case for such behavior, still using `Try` in the name makes it not very vlear)

Answer (score 7):

The answer seems to be hinted at (but not fully explained) by a note in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getboolean?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) in the documentation:

> This method does not parse the contents of a JSON string value.

But I was still confused until I found some [comments in a github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28132#issue-558436811) describing these methods. Here is a snippet of that comment (slightly elided, `**` added by me):

```
// InvalidOperationException if Type is not True or False
public bool GetBoolean();

// InvalidOperationException if Type is not Number 
// FormatException if value does not fit 
public decimal GetDecimal(); 
public double GetDouble(); 
public int GetInt32(); 

// InvalidOperationException if Type is not Number
// false if value **does not fit.** 
public bool TryGetDecimal(out decimal value); 
public bool TryGetDouble(out double value); 
public bool TryGetInt32(out int value);
```

So, it ultimately comes down to the difference between a `FormatException` and an `InvalidOperationException`.

The latter is used to indicate that the token's `ValueKind` (Number, String, True, False) does not match the expected type. The former (`FormatException`) is used a bit off-label from what one would normally expect; instead of being thrown for parsing errors* (ie. "1.sg" is not an `int`), it is thrown for **out of range errors**!

This is better understood if we look at the numeric overloads first. The non-`Try` variants either return a value or throw one of two exceptions: `InvalidOperationException` if the values are not numbers, `FormatExceptions` if they *don't fit*. From the documentation for `GetInt32`:

> **Exceptions**
>
> `InvalidOperationException`
>
> This value's `ValueKind` is not `Number`.
>
> `FormatException`
>
> The value cannot be represented as an `Int32`.

Compare this to the `Try` variants which throw one exception-- `InvalidOperationException` if the type is not a number--but **return** `false` if the value does not fit. From the documentation for `TryGetInt32`:

> **Exceptions**
>
> `InvalidOperationException`
>
> This value's `ValueKind` is not `Number`.
>
> **Returns**
>
> Boolean `true` if the number can be represented as an `Int32`; otherwise, `false`.

In this case, "doesn't fit" means that the value is too large/small for the underlying type, ie. greater than `int.MaxValue` when using `[Try]GetInt32`

Now let us get back to the case of `booleans` where you've rightly noticed there is only a non-`Try` variant. Looking at the comments in the same github issue we see this:

```
// InvalidOperationException if Type is not True or False
public bool GetBoolean();
```

And the documentation:

> **Exceptions**
>
> `InvalidOperationException`
>
> This value's  `ValueKind` is neither `True` nor `False`.

What's missing here is the `FormatException` and the "doesn't fit" case. As we've seen above in the case of numbers the `Try` variant gives us detection of "yes this is a number, but it's out of the appropriate range". `Booleans` only have two possible values--`true` and `false`--there's no range to detect, there's no `FormatException` to distinguish from. Similar with `strings`--its either a `string` token or its not.

What's important to note is that in all cases an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown if the `ValueKind` doesn't match what is expected by the method. A hypothetical `TryGetBoolean` wouldn't return `false` if it encountered a `string` value of "abc", it would throw an `InvalidOperationException` because the `ValueKind` wasn't `True` or `False`. **But that's already what `GetBoolean` does!** So theres no need for a seperate method.

* **Note**: There's no parsing error because the methods don't actually attempt to *parse* numbers/bools inside of a json `string` token, they only consider values of the correct token type. In otherwords, quoted numbers/bools are not currently supported:

```
{
   "number": 1234,
   "notNumber": "1234",
   "bool": true,
   "notBool": "false"
}
```

There is currently (2020-05-30) a [request to add support](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/39473&ved=2ahUKEwiYiYGAqtvpAhUCSN8KHUpPBqUQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw14QsCaJym86mMqF9cGMFd5&cshid=1590833111955) for this. At which time we may see a change to the availability/functionality of the `TryGet` methods.

Comment: My answer is 12 minutes late to the party--as I've been typing it on my cell. It hits at some of the points made by the other answer but in a bit more detail so I'm chosing not to remove it